# Non-compiled directive of child tag in ngRepeat parent

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I wanted uibTooltip directive instead of native `title` HTML atribute. Then, I got a directive that provides an automatic permutation of attributes before compiling.

The troubles are in ngRepeat directives if tag with affected attributes is inside.

You can see it [here](https://jsfiddle.net/b3r9x3u1/2/) (a JSFiddle testing example).

Comment: Please elaborate about what is exactly your problem or question.

Comment: Click JSFiddle link. You will see the different behaviour between two button groups. The second one is wrong. Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/7ubhz1jf/) is a solution! It is success if we compile inside `postLink` function.

Answer (score 2):

because this directive use terminal and when you use button inside `<li>`

`<li><button type="button" ng-repeat="btn in vm.buttons" class="btn btn-default" title="Add" ng-click="vm.add()"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></button></li>`

this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18996602/5429428) is well explained about terminal and priority.

Comment: So, I can never use this terminal directive in mixing with ngRepeat directive, right?

Comment: you can like in first example you have used.

Comment: What!? What do you mean?

Comment: you can use this as `<button type="button" ng-repeat="btn in vm.buttons" class="btn btn-default" title="Add" ng-click="vm.add()"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></button>`

directive and ng-repeat should be on same tag

Comment: I know. I have to consider that, as a child tag, there is no solution?

Comment: yeah, no solution for that