# Why is ngif ignoring priority level?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-if

I have created a custom directive with a priority of 1000. In the directive's compile function I am removing `ng-if` from the element. My assumption is that since `ng-if` has a lower priority of 600, it should not get compiled.

**app.js**

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {

});
app.directive('myDirective', function(){
  return {
    priority: 1000,
    compile: function(element){
      angular.element(element).removeAttr('ng-if').removeAttr('my-directive1');
    }
  };
});
app.directive('myDirective1', function(){
  return {
    compile: function(){
      console.log('in mydirective1');
    }
  };
});
```

**index.html**

```
<div my-directive ng-if="false" my-directive1>
  This div should be visible.
</div>
```

I have created another directive to check if my understanding of priority is correct. `myDirective` is successfully removing `myDirective1`, but not `ngIf`.

Following is the plunker link:

https://plnkr.co/edit/86mauwbt5I2aV4aoySpz?p=preview

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure why priorities does not work that way. I can suggest using terminal to eliminate lower priority directives. Here is updated [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/tUBOvazMZVsesasALjVV?p=preview).

```
app.directive('myDirective', function(){
  return {
    priority: 1000,
    terminal: true,
    compile: function(element){
      //element.removeAttr('ng-if').removeAttr('my-directive1');
    }
  };
});
```

Also see these questions about `terminal`:

- [How to understand the `terminal` of directive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15266840/how-to-understand-the-terminal-of-directive)
- [Why use terminal: true instead of removing lower priority directives?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18969610/why-use-terminal-true-instead-of-removing-lower-priority-directives)

Comment: Thanks for the reply.